# concatenating multiple rows Pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-ml

I need to merge following data into one row:

```
vector_no_stopw_df.select("filtered").show(3, truncate=False)



  +----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|filtered                                                                                                                                                                                                                          |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[, problem, population]                                                                                                                                                                                                           |
|[tyler, notes, global, population, increase, sharply, next, century, , almost, growth, occurring, relatively, underdeveloped, africa, south, asia, , contrast, , population, actually, decline, countries]                        |
|[many, economists, uncomfortable, population, issues, , perhaps, arent, covered, depth, standard, graduate, curriculum, , touch, topics, may, culturally, controversial, even, politically, incorrect, thats, unfortunate, future]|
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

so that it looks like

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|filtered                                                                                                                                                                                                                          |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[, problem, population,tyler, notes, global, population, increase, sharply, next, century, , almost, growth, occurring, relatively, underdeveloped, africa, south, asia, , contrast, , population, actually, decline, countries,many, economists, uncomfortable, population, issues, , perhaps, arent, covered, depth, standard, graduate, curriculum, , touch, topics, may, culturally, controversial, even, politically, incorrect, thats, unfortunate, future]|
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I know this is trivial. but cannot find solution. I tried `concat_ws` it did not work as well.

The `concat_ws`, I executed generates (`vector_no_stopw_df.select(concat_ws(',', vector_no_stopw_df.filtered)).collect()`) as follows:

```
[Row(concat_ws(,, filtered)='one,big,advantages,economist,long,time,council,economic,advisers,,years,ago,ive,gotten,know,follow,lot,people,thinking,,started,cea,august,,finished,july,,,first,academic,year,,fellow,senior,economists,paul,krugman,,lawrence,summers'),
 Row(concat_ws(,, filtered)='isnt,going,happen,anytime,soon,meantime,,tax,system,puts,place,much,higher,marginal,rates,people,acknowledge,people,keep,focusing,federal,income,taxes,alone,,marginal,rates,top,around,,percent,leaves,state'),
 Row(concat_ws(,, filtered)=',,
```

**Here is the solution just in case if somebody else needs it**:

I went ahead and used python's `itertools` library.

```
vector_no_stopw_df_count=vector_no_stopw_df.select("filtered").collect()
vector_no_stopw_df_count[0].filtered
vector_no_stopw_list=[i.filtered for i in vector_no_stopw_df_count]
```

**flatten the list**

```
from itertools import chain
flattenlist= list(chain.from_iterable(vector_no_stopw_list))
flattenlist[:20]
```

**Result**:

```
['',
 'problem',
 'population',
 'tyler',
 'notes',
 'global',
 'population',
 'increase',
 'sharply',
 'next',
 'century',
 '',
 'almost',
 'growth',
 'occurring',
 'relatively',
 'underdeveloped',
 'africa',
 'south',
 'asia']
```

Comment: What is the condition that groups the rows? How do you know which 3 rows need to be merged into one?

Comment: I added a crude pythonic way to solve this. I wanted to solve it via pyspark but could not solve it, so went ahead used itertools. See above

Comment: And in fact, i do not want to merge which with which. I just wanted to create a flattened list.

Answer (score 1):

In a way, you are looking for the reverse of [`explode`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=collect_list#pyspark.sql.functions.explode).

You can use [`collect_list`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=collect_list#pyspark.sql.functions.collect_list) for this:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions as F
df.groupBy(<somecol>).agg(F.collect_list('filtered').alias('aggregated_filters'))
```